# What is the meaning if all IoT hacked by Mirai all over the world identify themselves on my server since 15 days in the rhythm of 180 unique IoT/h?

Tags: ddos, iot

In the past 15 days **57,000 unique Mirai IoT devices** have attempted to connect and it’s constantly growing (180 new IPs/h). 88.9% come one time and never come back. We have checked. It’s Mirai botnet, but why this way? They don’t attack. **Is it a countdown?** What will happen when all of them identified themselves?

It's a big server (64 cores, 18TB hdd, 1Tbps) in a datacenter and the 3 IP's are recent. This server has a firewall with Telnet closed (never used) and Fail2ban. I'm the owner of this server and I'm in a real terrorist and cyberterrorist context in Europe (Intelligence activity). So this situation can be really a sign of something else.

[image]

Comment: They are trying to attack you (they are attempting to connect to your Telnet port). Something on your network made it so the botnet registered your IP as being a vulnerable IoT device, and they are trying to log in.

Comment: No, I don't think so. 180 new IP every hours, days and night for 1 to 3 packets only and since 15 days, that's not an attack. Definitively not. It's too much constant.

Comment: Define 'attack'. You mean a DDoS. I mean an attempt to gain access without authorization.

Comment: I just changed the question's description above. Please take a look on it. Strictly 180 unique attempts per hour since 350 hours??? I could believe if it was sometimes 50 attempts, sometimes 450. No, it's 170-190 attempts each hour during 350 hours, non stop.

Comment: You are making an assumption that they are "identifying themselves". Start with the facts, then posit some theories. It's difficult for us to deal with your theories as a starting point (X/Y Problem).

Comment: Yes, I have a suppositions (in my activities, people ask me to enounce suppositions), but I try to find other technical reasons to justify that I get constantly 180 attempts per hour. That's the main point of this question. Can you explain why 180 unique IoT/h during 360 hours try to connect to this server and still growing?

Comment: You only added details of your server to your question. That doesn't change anything, except that the IPs are recent. The previous owners of the IP may have been a C&C and its bots are trying to connect.

Comment: The old version of this server was running in DYN. On October 19, hackers succeeded to fully delete it. I restarted a new version on October 20 in Europe. On 21, DYN is attacked. On 23, a European country is attacked... On November 1st, I got low level attacks on computer and mobile and since 15 days, this... the same botnet than DYN...